# Maven archetype problem

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I am a newbie to maven. I have installed apache archiva in my machine to use as maven-proxy. My purpose is that I want  to generate a sample project structure using maven archiva plugin. I have uploaded required artifact using archiva for that.

When I run mvn archetype:generate it should ask me for the rest of the parameters. But instead it is giving me the following errors. Which indicates I have means maven shared plugin. But I have also uploaded the maven shared plugin artifact using archiva.

Here is the stack trace

```
F:\MavenTests\simple>mvn archetype:generate 
[INFO] Scanning for projects... 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>> 
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<< 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom --- 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 0.276s 
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 18 17:11:05 ALMT 2011 
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Exe 
lugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/MavenInvocationException 
[ERROR] ----------------------------------------------------- 
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0 
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy 
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/mae/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.0/maven-archetype-plugin-2.0.jar 
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/mae/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar 
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 4 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] realm =    maven.api 
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy 
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 21 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.sonatype.aether from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.personality from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.logging from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.context from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.container from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.configuration from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.component from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainerException from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusConstants from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.MutablePlexusContainer from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.DuplicateChildContainerException from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultContainerConfiguration from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultComponentRegistry from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.ContainerConfiguration from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.ComponentRegistry from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.classworlds from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.apache.maven from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenInvocationException 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

I am stumbled upon here. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is not much use in installing archiva on your own computer. (It's only good if you share it with someone) - so for start try to cut of the maven-proxy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [help link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException) points out, it looks like you may have a corrupt jar, in this case maven-invoker-2.0.x.jar. You can examine your local repository and verify it and if required delete it and retry.

It is also possible that your archiva itself has the corrupt jar in which case you need to delete it there.

Comment: Thanks man. Probably my archetype plugin was corrupted. I deleted maven-archetype-plugin from my local repository. Then run the mvn archetype:generate. Then maven downloads all the required jars from specified repositories. After that I have provided required inputs and project structure generates.