# can't create java project by maven on command line , Windows

Tags: java, maven

command line input: `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.azalea.web -DartifactId=test -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

errors as follows:

> failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2 generate: org/dom4j/DocumentException

that's it ! thanks at first

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6044153/1570834

Comment: thanks first.and i delete all packages about maven,then rerun the code,it works !